# What programs/distro are being run in these screenshots?

Tags: screenshot

Stumbling across (literally, via stumbleupon) I found some very cool linux desktop screenshots, and one was a screenshot of terminator from a question asked on this website. The bottom-left corner features a task manager/system monitor of sorts running in a terminal, what is the command to open this?

[image: im1]

In this other picture, (from linuxkungfu.org) someone has a screenshot of a -very- sexy looking, nerdy tech desktop with what I'm guessing are transparent? terminals running various programs, and what looks like an IRC program front + center....can anyone tell me what distro this individual is using?

[image: im2]

Comment: maybe one of wms mentioned here http://www.internetling.com/2008/07/16/the-big-x-window-manager-guide-with-screenshots/

Comment: @wojox There's a user called wojox on AU: http://askubuntu.com/users/2973/wojox  I do not believe in coincodences ;)

Comment: my desktop looked quite similar back in the days. All program are console programs and I guess the terminal is `aterm`

Comment: the info in the top right is probably by [Conky](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conky_(software))

Answer (score 2):

The command you want that is shown in the bottom left of this screenshot is `top`

[image]

Comment: Thanks josh, any idea about the 2nd screenshot? I guess reading through some of the text on that #irc channel he is on suggests it is a mandrake distro...

Comment: you can try htop too

Comment: The top shot is either sudo aptitude update or sudo apt-get update

Comment: This guy is cool. : ) Yes top and @ robin I'm an apt-get guy. : ) That looks like Awsome WM with irssi, mutt and gkrellm maybe.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, look at the star at the left-bottom. It's mandrake. Mutt is used for Mail, and Irssi for IRC. If you see some of the e-mails they discuss topics for the year 2004. It wasn't until 2005 when Mandrake joined Conectiva to become Mandriva.

So it's an old Mandrake distro ;-) I guess it's Mandrake 10

Answer (score 0):

1st image:
Top left and the right hand side are normal command line images;

At the bottom right it shows `top`. It should be installed on your system. Otherwise `sudo apt-get install top` to install it. There is an alternative version of top called htop (`sudo apt-get install htop`) that has some nice extras. Comparison of the 2:

top and htop:
[image: top][image: htop]

The 2nd image is from Mandrake. `mutt` is a command line email program that also let's you use attachments. You can also use `mutt` in Ubuntu: `sudo apt-get install mutt`. If you have mail set up on your system `mutt` will use that otherwise you will also need to set mail up yourself.